# Show parent product only, not children

Tags: configurable-product, magento-community, ce-1.9.1.0

So I have been working hard to learn Magento but made a change sometime back and I'm not sure how to fix it. When I display all products of a particular category it is showing all products instead of a single configurable product. Example: Master product is "box" configurable option are "size" and "color" of the box. My product page shows all the different sizes and colors instead of 1 box with the price range of available options.
I don't make changes to the contents of files, just in the admin console, so I am assuming the fix is in there somewhere. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the visibility field of the simple products and the configurable product. The simple ones should have it "not visible individually" and the configurable one must have it "catalog and search". Rebuild the indexes when you are done.

Comment: Thanks. That looks right now but the products don't show the possible price range nor do they change when I select options that would affect the price....maybe a template issue but it worked before.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot guess your this other issue.

Comment: all good...thanks for the help on that first part :)